# How to access a PHP Exception's Inner Exception

Tags: php, soap, exception, soap-client

When I make [`__soapCall`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php) (client pointing to a WSDL) and the request is invalid in the server side, the caught exception's message is coming out as general as this:

> An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the **inner exception** for details.

This is an example of one of my try-catch blocks:

```
try {
    $soapCallResult = $client->myWSDLMethod(array(...));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception in myWSDLMethod: ',  $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

When I var_dump the [`getTrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.gettrace.php), the array only points to the file and line where I make this call, which is not useful at all... It seems there is no `getInnerExceptionMessage()` method in the [Exception class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) or something remotely similar to that. So how should I access that inner exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `var_dump($e->detail)`, you can see the entire Exception's **detail** object and access the inner exception's message through the following path:

```
$e->detail->ExceptionDetail->InnerException->Message
```

You may be interested in printing more fields from this object. Here's a dump:

```
object(stdClass)[?]
  public 'ExceptionDetail' => 
    object(stdClass)[?]
      public 'HelpLink' => null
      public 'InnerException' => 
        object(stdClass)[?]
          public 'HelpLink' => null
          public 'InnerException' => null
          public 'Message' => string 'SERVER ERROR MSG: ...' (length=?)
          public 'StackTrace' => string '   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)'... (length=?)
          public 'Type' => string 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' (length=34)
      public 'Message' => string 'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.' (length=94)
      ...
```

Hope it helps.